# regarding passing tensorflow session as a parameter

Tags: tensorflow

In some tensorflow-based implementation, I have seen the implementation such as

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('[i] Creating the model...')
    net = FCNVGG(sess)
```

The FCNVGG is defined as follows, it also include some functions, which are skipped here.

```
class FCNVGG:
#---------------------------------------------------------------------------
def __init__(self, session):
    self.session     = session
```

The FCNVGG is a class to create deep learning model, e.g., fully convolutional neural network. What I don't understand is the mechanism of passing `sess` as a class parameter. What does a session look like, and why it can be passed as the parameter to a class?

Comment: Not really sure what your question is.